# from cv2 import cv2 VS import cv2 as cv2

Tags: python, opencv, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I'm working with a large package with lots of python scripts. Many of them import opencv. But the problem is that they import that either like

```
from cv2 import cv2
```

or like

```
import cv2.cv2 as cv2
```

which in both cases I get errors. In first case error is :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'cv2' from 'cv2' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

and in the second case

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.cv2'; 'cv2' is not a package
```

I can suppress these errors by changing the line to

```
import cv2 as cv2
```

but it's not practical to do so for all scripts.

I wanted to know what's the difference between these import methods first, and if there is a simple solution to that. My python version is 3.10. I'm using ubuntu 22.04 VM and installed opencv system wide using apt.

Comment: Can't you just `import cv2`?

Comment: It's not my concern. I can change the import line and fix the problem. my concerns are: first, why is this happening in my system? and how can I suppress this error with minimal effort as these import lines are repeated in tens of scripts.

Comment: "not practical" to open a couple dozen files and fix some imports? yeah sure there are tools to perform a mass string replace in multiple files. any IDE can do that, most text editors can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with **broken code**. Whoever wrote it made these **errors**.

**Correct:**

- **`import cv2 as cv`** (recommended)
- **`import cv2`** (okay but not recommended)

**Wrong**, as in: it is an error to write this:

- `from cv2 import cv2`
- `import cv2.cv2 as cv2`

Pointless:

- `import cv2 as cv2` because that is identical to `import cv2`

These errors can't be "suppressed". They are **fatal errors**.

The only way to fix this is to fix those import statements.

File a bug report with the author of that code. Make them fix their code. It is broken. It always has been. These broken imports were always wrong, even if they accidentally worked at some time.

Comment: They are not fatal errors. They are working as they are on other people's systems and those who wrote these codes are super professional software engineers.

Comment: I know they used PyCharm and they made the mistake of using bad import statements just to satisfy PyCharm's code analysis. This should be achieved instead using "stubs" that help an IDE understand a module with unusual (internal) import mechanics. The library user should never (have to) deal with this like they did.